# Parsing floating value from XML losing decimal places (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

I have a very awkward behaviour in C# (inside Unity, using VS2019) that is driving me crazy for days, now, and I really would appreciate your help.

I have a very simple XML file, in this simple case only containing a root node and a couple of attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root bit_depth="8" end_datetime="737061.75" start_datetime="737061">
</root>
```

And I try to read it:

```
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load( _projectFilePath );
    XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( "en-US" );

    string startTime = root.Attributes[ "start_datetime" ].Value;
    Debug.Log( "1st::: Read startTime number: " + startTime );
    double startTimeValue = double.Parse(startTime);
    Debug.Log( "2nd::: Parse startTime number: " + startTimeValue );

    string endTime = root.Attributes[ "end_datetime" ].Value;
    Debug.Log( "1st::: Read endTime number: " + endTime );
    double endTimeValue = double.Parse( endTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
    Debug.Log( "2nd::: Parse endTime number: " + endTimeValue );
```

The result is the following:

```
1st::: Read startTime number: 737061
2nd::: Parse startTime number: 737061

1st::: Read endTime number: 7,370618E+07
2nd::: Parse endTime number: 73706180000000
```

Just... why?!?!?!?! Why is it messing up that floating number to 7,370618E+07 when I explicitly parse a double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question, the doubles in your text are formatted with a **comma decimal separator**: `7,370618E+07`.  This implies that the [current locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locales-and-languages) on your computer (as represented by [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture?view=netframework-4.8)) uses this separator.

However, the numbers in the XML file are formatted using a **period decimal separator**: `737061.75`.  [`double.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Double_Parse_System_String_) will not parse them correctly, as the input string is *interpreted using the formatting information in a [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=netframework-4.8) object that is initialized for the current thread culture.*  I was able to reproduce this problem using a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0XUZGt) by changing the current culure to `new CultureInfo("de-DE")`.

Since XML files are generally formatted using an invariant culture, you should parse using [invariant settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo?view=netframework-4.8):

```
double startTimeValue = double.Parse(startTime, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
double endTimeValue = double.Parse(endTime, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Or, use [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.8):

```
double startTimeValue = double.Parse(startTime, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double endTimeValue = double.Parse(endTime,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Better yet use the utilities from the [`XmlConvert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
double startTimeValue = XmlConvert.ToDouble(startTime);
double endTimeValue = XmlConvert.ToDouble(endTime);
```

This class *provides methods for converting between common language runtime types and XML Schema definition language (XSD) types. When converting data types, the values returned are locale-independent.*  It thus encapsulates details about XML conventions for formatting of primitive types.

Demo fiddle #2 showing the above fixes [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bEXfTc).

---

As another, even easier alternative, try parsing your XML with [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(_projectFilePath);

var startTimeValue = (double)doc.Root.Attribute("start_datetime");
var endTimeValue = (double)doc.Root.Attribute("end_datetime");
```

LINQ to XML's [`XATtribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute?view=netframework-4.8#operators) supports direct casting to `double` or `decimal` eliminating the need for any manual parsing.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOpS8E).

---

Finally, in your code you do:

```
double endTimeValue = double.Parse(startTime);
```

I assume that this is a typo in your question and should be instead:

```
double endTimeValue = double.Parse(endTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I use "InvariantInfo" I simply get the same results as before, unfortunately. When I use XmlConvert I receive an exception of an invalid data formati reading the value of endTime...

Comment: @Allwo - I was able to reproduce your problem here https://dotnetfiddle.net/0XUZGt, and my solutions here https://dotnetfiddle.net/bEXfTc.  So either 1) There's something broken on unity3d, or 2) You aren't showing us a real [mcve].  Can you give details about your unity3d environment and version, and show how you initialize the `node` variable?  Currently your code does not compile since `node` is not defined.  I assumed it was `document.DocumentElement` but maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I exchanged "node" by "root" in the code of the question, which was the root node. As @Maxim_A suggested, to, I found that reading an XML string return a correct result, reading it from the XML file returns some converted stuff. What happens when you take the XML string to a file and load it?

Comment: @Allwo - If reading from a string works correctly but reading from a file does not, then there's something broken with the `XmlTextReader` used internally by `XmlDocument` on unity -- since `XmlTextReader` should not even be *attempting* to recognize and parse text values as doubles, and certainly does not do so on .Net or .Net core.  One possibility would be to manually create your own `XmlReader` using `XmlReader.Create()` as shown here, and see if the problem goes away: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T24LjY.  Also, can you use LINQ to XML on unity?

Comment: @Allwo - Also, I updated all my fiddles to read from a file rather than from a string.  The fixes still work.

Comment: I found the problem. All your answers were correct and I could reproduce them working correctly in other classes. Internally, the input XML path got changed and led to another file, which contained the numbers in a different format. Thank you very much for your aid, it helped me exluding the options to track down the real mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in Visual Studio and dotnetfiddle and got the following result.

```
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml("<root bit_depth=\"8\" end_datetime=\"737061.75\" start_datetime=\"737061\"></root >");

        string startTime = document.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["start_datetime"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine("1st::: Read startTime number: " + startTime);
        double startTimeValue = double.Parse(startTime);
        Console.WriteLine("2nd::: Parse startTime number: " + startTimeValue);

        string endTime = document.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["end_datetime"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine("1st::: Read endTime number: " + endTime);
        double endTimeValue = double.Parse(startTime);
        Console.WriteLine("2nd::: Parse endTime number: " + endTimeValue);

        1st::: Read startTime number: 737061
        2nd::: Parse startTime number: 737061
        1st::: Read endTime number: 737061.75
        2nd::: Parse endTime number: 737061
```

I advise you to check the encoding of your file and read it also with the same encoding. And also check the localization installed on the computer.

Comment: I added System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo( "en-US" ); to the beginning of my function but it did not make a difference. Even though I have another language setting on my computer, I cannot believe I have to change my entire working environment to achieve a correct XML floating parsing. I just want to have exactly the number that is written in my XML file, no unrequested conversion of it.

Comment: @Allwo if you use my option to load a string as an XML document, do you still have a parsing problem?

Comment: No, in fact then it is fine with the LoadXML. Is the key some language encoding inside the XML file? My header right now is a simple <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: var SourceFile = File.ReadAllText("path_to_file", Encoding.UTF8);
document.LoadXml(SourceFile); try this way to read your file and load the text of the file into the document

Comment: Results the same false 7,370618E+07 and 73706180000000

Comment: The error was a corrupt input file. Your sultions are correct. Thank you for your help!